# HTTP Error 403 Forbidden Issue in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I have latest version of wordpress along with woocommerce installed. Problem I am facing for last couple of months is that sometimes when I try to access website from my Windows 10 laptop, it shows blank page -

[image]

It happens regardless of which browser I am using on my laptop. I tried using Chrome, Firefox and Edge. When I clear the history and cache of browser, my website starts to load fine. The issue affects entire site including admin section, home page or any other page.

For some reason, this issue emerges only on my laptop. I never faced this issue on my android phone. I even checked loading the website simultaneously on my phone and laptop. While it loaded properly on mobile, I got the same issue on laptop.

I decided to check source code of the page when it shows blank. In the source code I could see that it is showing Error "**HTTP Error 403 – Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource"**.

The source code is mentioned below. Could somebody tell what this issue is? I have another wordpress website on the same hosting plan and it never face this issue. Site name is oldbookdepot(dot)in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("first-header").innerHTML = "HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden";
      document.getElementById("second-sub-header").innerHTML = "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource";
      var get=document.getElementsByTagName("A");
      for(i=0; i<get.length; i++){
        get[i].removeAttribute("onmouseover");
        get[i].removeAttribute("onmouseout");
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/errors/MultiDomainHosting.php", true);
  xhttp.send();

  </script>
<style>

.wrapper{
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
  background: none !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.header-container {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: larger;
}
.header-container > p,h1 {
  padding:5px;
}
.header-container > p {
  color: #707070;
}
.header-container > h1 {
  color: #333333;
}
.content-container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #202020;
  height: 635px;
  width: 100%;
}
.dynamic-content {
  position: relative !important;
  padding: 0 10em 0 10em;
  top: -50px;
}
.dynamic-content > div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  height: 550px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .dynamic-content > div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 2px;
    border-color: #e1e1e1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: auto;
  }
  .dynamic-content {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .content-container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px)  {
  .dynamic-content > div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-color: #e1e1e1;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: auto;
  }
  .dynamic-content {
    padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
    top: 0;
  }
  .content-container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <div class="header-container">
    <h1 id="first-header"></h1>
    <p id="first-sub-header"></p>
    <p id="second-sub-header"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic-content" id="demo">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the /errors/MultiDomainHosting.php file and console log, there may be .js errors or connection issues

Comment: You should enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG.

in wp-config.php find:

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
And replace it with:

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
Run your wp-admin and check inline errors and error.log in wp-content folder.

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski I couldn't find any /errors/MultiDomainHosting.php file on the server.

Comment: @PrashantSuthar I did what you asked but it didn't show any error on either wp-admin or error log file.

Comment: You're using an ajax call on this file here - xhttp.open("GET", "/errors/MultiDomainHosting.php", true). What is the desired content for this page? You have an empty html, no ajax file, what do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, the cause of a random white screen of death (WSOD) that goes away without intervention is not enough memory allocated to the hosting account or WordPress.

1. [WordPress memory settings][1]https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP
2. For allocating more memory to PHP (which WordPress cannot exceed, even if you tell it to use more), finding where to make the change is a bit more tricky.
   cPanel and Plesk let you do it via the panels... hopefully you make the changes there. Otherwise you'll need to find the php.ini file in use, and update the `memory_limit = ...` line.

One thing to keep in mind that Plesk (and I imagine cPanel, too) auto-generates a lot of files based on settings elsewhere. Watch for headers on php.ini files that state "this file is auto-generated and will be overwritten - do not make changes here." By making changes to this file, if you solve the problem with the WSOD, it'll be back after the next server restart.

**Can't find anywhere in the system where you can make the change to PHP memory limits?**
In a lot of shared hosting environments, standard user's are at the mercy of the hosting company when it comes to allotted memory. Though from my experience, some have increased the size for me since they might not get a lot of such requests. Contact them before spending too much time unsuccessfully trying to find where to make the modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kindly tell me if its memory issue then why its not affecting website when I access it through android phone. I load the website on laptop and android phone together and while it works fine on phone, it will show error on laptop.

Comment: You're welcome. To answer on the randomness and selective nature of the problem, some possible reasons are: more aggressive caching on your mobile Android device, caching by your mobile provider at the network level, different plugins getting activated for Android vs desktop. Or, my memory theory is simply wrong, and the comments above (pointing you to more technical troubleshooting) are your best lead. But in a large chunk of cases, I solved very random WSOD problems by ensuring the memory requirements are met.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my hosting provider to increase memory for the website since I could't find any option in cPanel. On a different note, I just found out on cPanel that I am still using php 5.6 for my websites even though higher versions up to 7.1 is available. Do you think it may be the reason that could be causing the issue? Will upgrading php to latest version help?

Comment: PHP 7 looks to be more optimised, and some sources I found suggest it'll use roughly 20% less of memory. With my own sites, I wasn't able to find info on which plugins are PHP 7+ compatible. Drupal core for example will run on 7.1, but not yet 7.2. I found some scripts that I wasn't able to implement that supposedly test for overall compatibility... without getting too verbose and theoretical, I'd suggest try PHP 7 on a dev server, and test the hell out of it... if it looks good, make the switch, but watch error logs like a hawk watches for its next meal.